# A modulo system equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Solve this equation system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2+2y+xy\equiv 3\pmod 7\\ 
x+2y^2+x^2y\equiv 4\pmod 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I tried to turn them to linear equation to use the Chinese reminder theorem but I can't.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem is for two different, relatively prime moduli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Note that when you add the equations together, you get
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+y)(2y+x+x^2)\equiv 0\pmod 7.\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be a doddle from here ?

Comment: So one solution would be $y\equiv6\pmod7$ (and could then solve for $x$), but what if $2y+x+x^2\equiv0\pmod7$?

Comment: Hm... What if we use the trial-and-errors tactic to solve the rest? Like, assume x is...